# How can I add a line parameter like -opengl on World of Warcraft in PlayOnLinux?

Tags: opengl, playonlinux

I would like to add the `-opengl` parameter to a file which is in

`/home/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/WorldOfWarcraft/drive_c/Program Files/world of Warcraft/Wow.exe`

Comment: Are you open it with Wine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your World of Warcraft wine drive folder, go to the WTF folder and then edit your `config.wtf` file and add this line at the end (or modify it if already exists): `SET gxApi "opengl"`.

This will make your `wow.exe` use opengl everytime you run it.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot!. But I didn't solve my problem :(. I want to fix these pixelated trees: http://i54.tinypic.com/ih76fq.png - However, you've solved this specific question, so I'll accept this answer =P. Thanks.

Comment: I can help you with that :) Can you try to run the exact same thing on ubuntu-2d and tell me if anything changed? Also knowing your graphics card would be nice.

Comment: Dude, you're a genius. I tried changing to Ubuntu-2d LOGGING OUT and didn't fix it. But I recently tried RESTARTING my laptop and using the same Ubuntu-2d session and WORKS!. Thank you a lot man.

Comment: wlcm, glad to help! FOR THE HOOOOOORDE!!!!

Comment: Very useful! A diferrent way is to create a DWORD key in CURRENT_USER/Software/Blizzard/Warcraft with the name "Afx OpenGL" and set it to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Open your Terminal, go to the directory where you have installed WoW, and run `WoW.exe` manually:

```
wine WoW.exe -opengl
```